# Assign FormWindowState with Option Strict On

Tags: vb.net, strict

Form.WindowState uses the FormWindowState enumeration to set the value to "minimized", "maximized", "normal". On closing a form i cast these states to integer and export them. However i can't assign them on reloading the form by using

```
Me.WindowState = CInt(getMySetting())
```

because i am using

```
Option Strict On
```

which disallows this implicit conversion from int to FormWindowState. FormWindowState does not have any constructors i can use, so i don't know how i can create the matching FormWindowState by using the corresponding Integer. Do you have any suggestions except for turning Option Strict off? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Me.WindowState = CType(CInt(getMySetting()), FormWindowState)
```

You have to cast the `Integer` to `FormWindowState` (presuming that it's a valid value)

But the more robust/readable way would be to use the `FowmWindowState`-enum in the settings directly. You can do that. You just have to find it in the correct namespace(see the picture below):

[image]

Now this strongly typed code works:

```
Me.WindowState = My.Settings.DefWindowState
```

Comment: Thank you, converting with CType works! I am not quite sure what you mean with your suggestion though: Since i don't know which WindowState i will be setting (i retrieve the state from an external file), i can't specify it in the settings, correct?

Comment: @HW: then you can ignore the second part. I thought that you were reading it from [`My.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx).